# IOS long data entry screen

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, info

I am developing an IOS swift app with multiple pages requesting information from the user.  One of the pages will request address and personal information on one page.  Unfortunately it will not fit on one page on a smaller device.  Should I use a scrollview to allow the user to scroll down and enter all required information?

Is there any other control you would recommend using.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have a couple of options.

1) Break down the screens asking for information even more but be sure they are logically grouped. (Addresses with addresses, personal info together, security questions together etc etc). Not ideal because the user might get tired of being asked questions but it works.

2) This is my preferred way and it is the one you mentioned. A scrollview. You could have a bunch of uitextfields one under the other and only after everything you need is filled in, the user is given the opportunity to go to the next screen.

I am sure there might be other ways to  accomplish your task but these have been my top two ways of gathering lots of information.